# Optimizing nested nan removal from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got an unusual data frame that contains positional (2D coordinate) data in a pandas frame, it looks like:

```
                                          0  ...                                          2
0        [110.001220703125, -85.76113891601562]  ...    [79.7227783203125, -131.07473754882812]
1        [118.484619140625, -73.60284423828125]  ...                                 [nan, nan]
2     [125.63433837890625, -56.826995849609375]  ...                                 [nan, nan]
3     [130.34637451171875, -38.804656982421875]  ...                                 [nan, nan]
4           [129.54150390625, -32.026611328125]  ...                                 [nan, nan]
```

The reason for the nan's is that it comes from a tracking neural net, and those values have an associated certainty below threshold, so I've masked these. I realize I can't use .dropna() directly since technically a set of empty sets is a full set so [nan, nan] != nan. Therefore, I made this function:

```
    IndexToDrop_List = []
    for Ind in Frame.index.values:
       Row = Frame.iloc[Ind,]
       for Vals in Row:
          if np.isnan(Vals[0]) == True:
              IndexToDrop_List.append(Ind)
              break
Frame = Frame.drop(IndexToDrop_List).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which takes the index value of the row and removes the entire row if an [nan, nan] coordinate is found. It works, however, I was wondering if there was a way to use .apply() to shorten this, these datasets can get pretty large and any time saved would be ideal.

The expected output:

```
                                             0  ...                                          2
0          [9.29730224609375, 184.36279296875]  ...     [-61.94122314453125, 153.804931640625]
1       [4.42108154296875, 184.70294189453125]  ...   [-65.76788330078125, 155.11004638671875]
2       [-1.9549560546875, 182.90460205078125]  ...      [-67.963134765625, 155.1727294921875]
3        [0.0401611328125, 177.62042236328125]  ...     [-68.549072265625, 146.52874755859375]
4      [36.03021240234375, 162.80792236328125]  ...     [-23.573974609375, 135.88336181640625]
```

Comment: how many columns are there in total?

Comment: Why not just store your data in a sane format, like one column per column of data, instead of lists containing two elements for each pair of columns? You can use hierarchical indexing if you want to group x and y pairs together.

Comment: @ZLi The number of columns are variable, it depends entirely on how many postures are tracked by the user in any recording. I see your answer, I'm going to try implementing it but it looks it'll work, so thank you! And I should add, I only look a the 0th value in the coordinate list because either both coordinates or none will be nan, as in the example frame.

Comment: @MadPhysicist So I initially stored these coordinates (they're actually vectors) in a hash map and thought it would be cleaner to work with if they were in a data frame. Since the index matches the frame number for all postures, then I can just delete rows at least one nan, rather than having to index.

Comment: @spitfire1x3. Expand your lists into separate columns. You should never store lists in a dataframe if you can avoid it. It's just shooting yourself in the foot on purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2],[3,4]], 'b':[[np.nan, 1], [2,3]]})
```

```
    a       b
0   [1, 2]  [nan, 1]
1   [3, 4]  [2, 3]
```

You could expand the columns to form a regular matrix and operate on it:

```
has_nan_idx = [np.isnan(np.array(df[c].to_list())).any(axis = 1) for c in df.columns]
df[~np.logical_or.reduce(has_nan_idx)]
```

```
    a       b
1   [3, 4]  [2, 3]
```